# Where apt and dpkg store temporary files (except the well-known /var/cache/apt/archives) during update?

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg

As I can see, /var/cache/apt/archives is the tip of the iceberg. Today, the update took 70 Mb to download (and took 70 Mb in /var/cache/apt/archives), but required over 400 Mb for installing (most of this space comes back, so it looks like temporary usage). Do apt and/or dpkg unpack them into another temporary directory before copying it over the old version? (Either way, it's not /tmp; my /tmp is a tiny tmpfs, much less than 400 Mb).

Comment: Deb packages are compressed, and usually unpacked into their final location. No intermediate temp directory is needed. If you are curious about a specific package, please specify. Your update today is logged in /var/log/apt.

Comment: So if some .deb takes space for full packed + unpacked sizes, it means THIS .deb is somehow configured to use temporary location, not to extract files directly to /usr/bin, /usr/lib etc? Or does it mean this .deb is unpacked directly to /usr/bin etc, but file bodies are still on disk because these files are busy, so they can't be removed „on the fly“ until package restarts?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the heart of your question is why do updates require additional space and where is that space used.

The answer to this question is that while the debs themselves take some amount of space to store, you can think of them like a compressed archive of files. Inside the deb there are instructions as to the contents of the deb as well as a location on disk for each file to be placed. As a package is updated by the author new libraries may be required or new functionality added. The additional space doesn't come from the debs themselves but from the uncompressed files of all the cumulative updates that you have for your system. This means that if there were substantial updates to some packages, more space is required than original

i.e. if Plex originally took 300M of space uncompressed with an original deb of 60M, a new deb of 70M in size might require an additional 100M of space on disk due to new features being rolled out

Comment: Most updates work like this:
1) Ask me for 470 Mb of space and 70 Mb to download.
2) Take 70 Mb (400 is free) for downloading.
3) Take 400 Mb (0 is free) for unpacking and replacing the old version (the question is about this stage).
4) Remove the old package (300 is free because newer one is slightly bigger).
5) Remove .deb from /var/cache/apt/archives (370 is free).
I understand why 370<470, but I don't understand why stage 3 takes 470 Mb (space for both packed .deb and unpacked files), not 170 Mb (space for packed .deb and difference between old and new versions).